# How to write a custom ember-data orm method using the store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to write an "active record" like method to filter out inactive models

Using the latest ember-data I usually pull in all employee records like so

```
var employees = this.store.all('employee');
```

Keep in mind that I'm doing this "filter" 100% client side because I have everything in memory. I use all the employees for a few parts of the app and need the "all" like behavior in these situations. But as I'm also allowing "active/ inactive" status I'd like to filter them down client side for a few features.

I wanted a nice way to query this using a simple filter and I thought it would be active-record like to extend the model and add this but I wanted some guidance first (ie- should I be doing this when the store is not injected into the model directly, and if yes how should I go about injecting this?)

If I shouldn't do this, what is the best way to get all employees and filter down to get only the active ones? (ie- can I just invoke store.all and apply the filter or do I need to work with this data differently) ?

(here is a sample of the filter I'm doing manually now)

```
return content.filter(function(apt) {                          
    return apt.get('employee').get('active') === true;         
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data's store has a `filter` method that has the same functionality as the `all` filter, aka live record array.

```
store.filter('employee', function(employee){
  return employee.get('active'); 
});
```